# The only geodesic of $S$ that passes through $p$ and cannot be extended for every value of the parameter is the meridian of $S$ through $p$.

Tags: differential-geometry

From Do Carmo's book:

> Let $S$ be the one-sheeted cone given by $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}, (x,y)\in \mathbb R^2,$ without the vertex $p_0 = (0,0,0). $ Given $p \in S,$ show that the only geodesics of $S$ that passes through $p$ and cannot be extended for every real value of the parameter are the meridians of $S$ through $p.$

Fixed $p\in S$, I know that $\gamma$ given by a meridian is a geodesic which cannot be extended, since it would contain the vertex $p_0\not\in S.$ 
*So we must show that any geodesic $\gamma$ through $p$ is such that
    it is extendable for every real value.*

The book suggests that we use Clairaut's relation $r\cos \theta  = const.$, where $r, \theta$ is the radius and angle of a parallel that $\gamma$ intersects, respectively.  From this relation we see that as $r$ increases (ie, as we move up over the one-sheeted cone) the angle $\theta$ must increase. I tried to use this information to conclude that $\gamma$ cannot be asymptotic to a meridian and hence it must pass through all meridians of $S$. But I don't see why this allows me to conclude that $\gamma$ is extendable.

Answer (score 1):

When $\theta\neq\pi/2$, $\cos\theta=c/r$ goes bigger as $r$ goes smaller. But note that $\cos\theta$ is smaller or equal to 1, which means $r$ cannot reach zero, instead it will converge to a value strictly larger than zero. In this case, the geodesic cannot even reach the vertex.